# Node.js:"Cannot read property 'toString' of undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, rest

I'm following a restApi course with Node.js, It's a blog API. my problem is when deleting a post for the unAuthorized user it first gives me a **500 error**

> "error": "Cannot read property 'toString' of undefined"

. but when doing it again it gives me

> Post not found with id of.

Of course, it supposed to give me

> not authorized to delete this post.

Update the post is also the same, I even tried to copy/paste the code from the course but the same problem.

**postController**

```
exports.deletePost = asyncHandler(async (req, res, next) => {
    const post = await Post.findByIdAndDelete(req.params.id); 
    if (!post) {
      return next(
        new ErrorResponse(`Post not found with id of ${req.params.id}`, 404)
      );
    }
    // Make sure user is post owner
  if (post.user.toString() !== req.user.id) {
    return next(
      new ErrorResponse(
        `User ${req.params.id} is not authorized to delete this post`,
        401
      )
    );
  }
  post.remove();

    res.status(200).json({ success: true, data: post});

});
```

***updatePost***

```
exports.updatePost = asyncHandler(async (req, res, next) => {
    let post = await Post.findById(req.params.id);
  
    if (!post) {
      return next(
        new ErrorResponse(`Post not found with id of ${req.params.id}`, 404)
      );
    }

  // Make sure user is post owner
  if (post.user.toString() !== req.user.id) {
    return next(
      new ErrorResponse(
        `User ${req.params.id} is not authorized to update this post`,
        401
      )
    );
  }

  post = await Post.findOneAndUpdate(req.params.id, req.body, {
    new: true,
    runValidators: true
  });

  res.status(200).json({ success: true, data: post });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could introduce a type check on the post.user object to ensure that the user exists within the post.

```
if (typeof post.user == "undefined" || post.user.toString() !== req.user.id)
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof

Comment: I thought it worked it first because it no longer gives me that error. but it still deletes the post anyway. any idea how to stop that?

Comment: I have altered my code so that it will stop the request.

Comment: The changes make it so that if the user cannot be found OR the id does not match the request user then the error response will be triggered.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried the code
`if (typeof post.user == "undefined" || post.user.toString() !== req.user.id)`

But after using this cause to get me an error 'User not Authorized' in my error handling.

In my case, I have to convert the `req.user.id` to an integer

```
if (post.user !== req.user.id.parseInt)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();
const fetchuser = require("../middleware/Fetchuser");
const Notes = require("../models/Notes.js");
const { body, validationResult } = require("express-validator");

router.get("/fetchnotes", fetchuser, async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const notes = await Notes.find({ user: req.user });

    res.json(notes);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error.message);
    res.status(500).send("error occured");
  }
});

router.post(
  "/addnotes",
  [
    body("title").isLength({ min: 5 }),
    body("description").isLength({ min: 3 }),
  ],
  fetchuser,
  async (req, res) => {
    try {
      const { title, description, tag } = req.body;

      const errors = validationResult(req);
      if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
        return res.status(400).json({ errors: errors.array() });
      }

      const note = new Notes({
        title,
        description,
        tag,
        user: req.user.id,
      });
      const savedNotes = await note.save();

      res.json(savedNotes);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error.message);
      res.status(500).send("error occured");
    }
  }
);
router.put("/updatenotes/:id", fetchuser, async (req, res) => {
  const { title, description, tag } = req.body;
  const newNote = {};
  if (title) {
    newNote.title = title;
  }
  if (description) {
    newNote.description = description;
  }
  if (tag) {
    newNote.tag = tag;
  }

  let note = await Notes.findById(req.params.id);
  if (!note) {
    return res.status(400).send("error occured");
  }

  if (note.user !== req.user.id.parseInt) {
    return res.status(401).json("user not allowed");
  }

  note = await Notes.findByIdAndUpdate(
    req.params.id,
    { $set: newNote },
    { new: true }
  );
  res.json(note);
});
module.exports = router;
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.